# How can I count the numbers of rows that a mysql query returned? and i want to calculate them using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

i have a database table

connection_td

```
id - zone - ageing_with_a -  ageing_with_b -  ageing_with_c   -  tatal_ageing  -  average
1     Abw        5days           1days             2days              8days      2.6days 
2     bbb        1days           5days             2days              8days      2.6days 
3     bbb        2days           3days             4days              9days      3days  
4     Abw        3days           2days             6days              11days     3.4days 
5     ccc        4days           4days             6days              14days     4.3days
```

Now i want to retrieve this data like in this tanle

```
id - zone - ageing_with_a - ageing_with_b - ageing_with_c   -  tatal_ageing  -  average
1     Abw         8               3               8                 19           6
2     bbb
3     ccc
```

hope you can understand what i want somebody please help me thanks

Comment: Please see in connection_tb there zones are repeating but in the result table zone will not repeat ....

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `GROUPBY` functions : [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

For example :

```
SELECT zone, SUM(ageing_with_a) , SUM(ageing_with_b) , SUM(ageing_with_c)  , SUM(tatal_ageing) , SUM(average)
FROM connection_td
GROUP BY zone
```

But I see that there is `days` strings in your data. You will have to remove this string and then cast (or convert) the result to number, in order to be able to use SUM function.

Something like `SUM(CAST(REPLACE(ageing_with_a ,'[a-z]+','')) AS DECIMAL(2,2))` would do the trick.

Or better : you change your columns types to DECIMAL or INTEGER depending of the need, and stop to store 'days' string inside. Then, the first query I gave here should work.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way will be to change the table column data type into "INT" and only store numbers at those columns.
then, a simple query like SUM will do the trick. But first you should change the columns data type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate your field should be **integer**. But now i can see it is **varchar**

Please make **integer** in your field.

Try this -

```
SELECT SUM(ageing_with_a), SUM(ageing_with_b), SUM(ageing_with_c) FROM connection_td GROUP BY zone
```

Answer (score 0):

---

if you want to add column values first you must use column as integer in database and put your days in database

and try this query

```
SELECT SUM(ageing_with_a), SUM(ageing_with_b), SUM(ageing_with_c) FROM connection_td GROUP BY zone
```